# Date format conforming to regional settings, but also including weekday

Tags: excel, vba

I know that if I set the numberformat `"m/d/yyyy"` using VBA, then that numberformat will adapt to the user regional settings. Some countries will see `3/12/2015` while others will see `2015-03-12`.

Is there a way set a numberformat that includes both date and weekday, such as `"dddd m/d/yyyy"` and have this conform to regional settings as well?

Comment: the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to concatenate the two together: something like this:  `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd"), " ", TEXT(TODAY(),"m/d/yyyy"))`  but doubt that's really what you need. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by setting `NumberFormat` to plain `"m/d/yyyy"` so it adapts to regional settings. Then read `NumberFormatLocal` to see what the actual resulting format is. Then prepend `"dddd "` to that.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1")
r.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
r.NumberFormatLocal = "dddd " & r.NumberFormatLocal
```

For example, with my regional settings, I get this:

[image]

Comment: I certainly learned something myself: I never realised before that `"m/d/yyyy"` would conform to regional settings. It doesn't do that when you specify it in Excel; only in VBA.